# How to substr or strpos this character

Tags: substring, strpos

Help me to get this character in one code

1. 4edtee3fdpd0h8o
2. kfz254yae7cw8fb
3. da84s08ifannjs6
4. a4x4c1eaki9ekw1

From this url :  all of this $char

1. httpq://199.91.153.79/c0l8y769haig/4edtee3fdpd0h8o/1-No%26Batak+%2B+JB.mp3
2. httpq://199.91.153.63/7otxr1alp53g/kfz254yae7cw8fb/1-Yes%26metalica.mp3
3. httpq://205.196.120.88/x0xa2u3s6utg/da84s08ifannjs6/1-Yes%26Mirrors.mp3
4. httpq://205.196.122.248/dv6dyax7o3eg/a4x4c1eaki9ekw1/1-Yes%26reggae.mp3

Thanks before..

Comment: did you already tried something with substr and strpos or do you want us to do the thinking?

Comment: Yes..
I have tried
substr($upload['links'][0]['direct_download'],33,19)

the results:
/4edtee3fdpd0h8o/1-
/kfz254yae7cw8fb/1-
g/da84s08ifannjs6/1
g/a4x4c1eaki9ekw1/1

Answer (score 0):

you need this regex

```
/httpq:\/\/([\d+]{1,3}[\.|\/])+[^\/]+\/(\S+)\/.*/
```

example:

```
$str = "httpq://199.91.153.63/7otxr1alp53g/kfz254yae7cw8fb/1-Yes%26metalica.mp3";
$regex = "/httpq:\/\/([\d+]{1,3}[\.|\/])+[^\/]+\/(\S+)\/.*/";
echo preg_replace($regex, "$2", $str);
```

Comment: thanks it works. but how if I delete 'q' character?
$str = "http://199.91.153.63/7otxr1alp53g/kfz254yae7cw8fb/1-Yes%26metalica.mp3";

Comment: Closed.. Answered..
Thanks Mr. vladkras